# Eliminating pattern matching on GADT when constructor known statically

Tags: haskell, ghc, compiler-optimization, algebraic-data-types

Let's say I have promoted data type:

```
data GADTConstructor = IntConstructor | StringConstructor
```

Then I create GADT:

```
data MyGADT (a :: GADTConstructor) where
    MyInt    :: Int -> MyGADT IntConstructor
    MyString :: String -> MyGADT StringConstructor
```

And pattern matching function:

```
printMyMyGADT :: MyGADT a -> IO ()
printMyMyGADT (MyInt i) = printInteger i
printMyMyGADT (MyString s) = printString s
```

Here actual GADT's constructor is uniquely determined by the GADT's type index which is known at compile time. Is it possible to force GHC to omit any pattern matching in runtime and generate code assuming that the actual branch is known statically?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that GHC can't do this without help (e.g. `RULES` pragmas). Anyway the overhead of matching on the GADT constructor won't matter as long as you have expensive `IO` operations like printing going on.

Comment: Thank your for suggestion. This is not for printing integers, real code read memory in tight loop and pattern matching introduces up to 60% overhead comparing to baseline code without pattern matching. I will try to optimize it with `RULES`

Comment: Note that this optimization would also have to interact with strictness analysis. Consider `printMyMyGADT (undefined :: MyGADT IntConstructor)`.

Answer (score 3):

Well when GHC compiles `printMyMyGADT` the type index `a` is not known of course (it's a variable) and information about `a` is not available at runtime either, so `printMyMyGADT` has to do a branch on which constructor it was passed.

If you have instead

```
printMyMyGADT' :: MyGADT IntConstructor -> IO ()
printMyMyGADT' (MyInt i) = printInteger i
```

then GHC is able to propagate the information that only the `MyInt` constructor is possible to the generated code and avoid a branch on the constructor.

If you call the original `printMyMyGADT` in a context where its type variable `a` is known to be `IntConstructor` and *if it is inlined* then GHC will simplify the inlined expression to something like `printMyMyGADT'` and again the branch will be avoided. This might also work for specialization, I'm not sure.

All of this is somewhat irrelevant in practice because in all cases `printMyMyGADT` needs to handle the case of being passed an unevaluated expression. The cost of branching on which of two constructors we see is not more than the cost of checking whether we have been passed a constructor in the first place.

Comment: I don't *think* specialization will help without a class. It might work to use `class MyPrint a where myPrint :: MyGADT a -> IO ()`, effectively splitting the two cases into two functions with a uniform API.